# MySQL: Limit number of results for each group in query based on results from another query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I would like to thank everyone in advance for any help you would share on this following issue.

In mysql I have the following tables:

select id, product_id from MembersProducts;

```
Member Products

id | product_id
1  | 2
1  | 3
1  | 4
1  | 5
1  | 6
2  | 5
2  | 6
```

select id, (TimesPerDay * TimesPerWeek) from Schedule;

```
Schedule
id | (TimesPerDay * TimesPerWeek)
1  | 2
2  | 1
```

I would like to create a query that generates the following table:

```
Member Products

id | product_id
1  | 2
1  | 3
2  | 5
```

My goal is to have the number of product_id limited by the (TimesPerDay * TimesPerWeek) column for each id.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT mp.*
FROM MembersProducts mp
LEFT JOIN Schedule s ON mp.id=s.id
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM MembersProducts mp2
       WHERE mp2.id=mp.id
       AND mp2.product_id<mp.product_id
) < s.TimesPerDay*s.TimesPerWeek
```

What this does is basically a "greatest-n-per-group" selection where `n` varies per group too.

The `WHERE` counts up how many other products have already been chosen and only selects them out if it hasn't chosen enough (enough being TimesPerDay*TimesPerWeek).

Comment: Thanks Coffee! I tested the code and was not able to get it to work. I only get the first 2 ids, and only 1 product_id per line (2 results). I did update the code... here is my update:[code](http://mikesturgill.com/uncategorized/code2/)

Comment: Perhaps that's because you don't have enough entries in MemberProducts to select, or because of your Schedules values? [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ed0b/1) is an sqlfiddle showing the query working on the data in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.id, e.product_id 
from (select @rank:=CASE WHEN @ranked <> id THEN 1 ELSE @rank+1 END as rank,
          id,
          product_id, 
          @ranked:=id 
      from 
          (select @rank := -1) a, 
          (select @ranked :=- 1) b, 
          (select * from member_products order by id) c
      ) e 
inner join (select id, (TimesPerDay * TimesPerWeek) as times from schedule) sch 
    on sch.id = e.id and e.rank <= sch.times;
```

Ugly looking, but this will do exactly what you need.

Comment: Hi Francisco, thank you very much for your reply! Sorry for the delay in response, just getting in from work. After trying the formula the inner join I think is working because the number of results per id is working correctly. the product_id is not unfortunately. It will show the same product_id 18 times then go to the next one. It always starts at 1. I did need to update the code to fit my exact need. Here is the update:http://mikesturgill.com/uncategorized/code/ (sorry the code didn't fit into the comment box and I couldn't add a second comment with the code in it)

Comment: Well, as long as you made it work and learned something along the way!